# Side-by-side and vertically stacked boxplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 3 different populations (staff types 1, 2, and 3) that are being evaluated along 3 variables (degree, weighted.degree, eccentricity) and am looking to view these in a single set of boxplots.

These boxplots should be placed side-by-side for each staff type for a given variable, and with 3 vertical stacked graphs by variable: something like a 3 x 3 matrix of boxplots.

My current code is producing the desired vertical stacking for the variables, but within each vertically stacked graph I have 1 aggregate boxplot where there should be 3 side-by-side (1 for each of the 3 staff types).

```
qp <- ggplot(data, aes(stafftype., value, fill=stafftype.))
+ geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(variable~., scales = "free_y")
```

Also note that each of the 3 side-be-side boxplots should be colored by stafftype, which I've been unsuccessful with.

[resulting boxplot graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8OKc.png)

Comment: Check out the gridExtra package.. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using the built-in `iris` data frame. We remove one of the measure columns so that we'll have three instead of four and then `melt` the data frame so that the three measure columns are stacked into "long" format. `Species` is analogous to `stafftype` and `variable` is analogous to the three evaluation variables (degree, weighted.degree, eccentricity).

```
library(reshape2)

ggplot(melt(iris[,-1], id.var="Species")) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(Species, value, colour=Species), show.legend=FALSE) +
  facet_grid(variable ~ .) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you want each plot in a separate panel, you can do this:

```
ggplot(melt(iris[,-1], id.var="Species")) +
  geom_boxplot(aes("", value, colour=Species), width=0.5, show.legend=FALSE) +
  facet_grid(variable ~ Species) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  labs(x="")
```

[image]

Comment: Your example is exactly what I wanted to accomplish! Thank you.

One complication is that my StaffType data are the integers 1/2/3, which seemed to cause a problem as R reads this as a continuous series vs. discrete; this issues is fixed by

"geom_boxplot(aes(group = cut_width(stafftype.,1)))"

to break the really wide boxplot that I was getting into 3 separate plots at intervals of "1". However, the default coloring of each StaffType is still done as if the StaffType are continuous ... instead of R/G/B my plots are shades of blue. Maybe I need to change my StaffType to a word instead.

Comment: Change `StaffType` to a factor. You can do this "on the fly" within the ggplot code: `aes(factor(StaffType), value, colour=factor(Stafftype))`

Comment: Bingo! Thanks very much.